# Authenticator for static website

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox

Is there any ready to go solution for hosting static website (Jekyll) with authentication against some service (like Dropbox, Git or Google-Drive)?

The idea behind that is to use Jekyll for writing technical notes for the private corporate blog.

Any suggestions are welcome. Cheers

Comment: https://blog.termian.dev/posts/static-site-auth/

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and Jekyll Auth seems to fit your needs. I do not experience with Jekyll but it seems pretty straight forward. Works with GitHub I believe.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/jekyll-auth/popularity

Comment: I already tried Jekyll Auth, but it wasn't that straightforward for me =( I spent a day on it and couldn't figure it out ... It is also gets more complicated, because it works in a pair with Heroku and I never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use HTTP basic auth. The disadvantage of such an approach is that all users would have the same username and password. This blog post explains how to add basic auth to a Jekyll site:

https://www.aerobatic.com/blog/password-protect-a-jekyll-site

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Aerobatic